# can Belongs_to work without has_many or has_one

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations, belongs-to

I am studying Belongs_to association, I have used following models, in that every order belongs to the customer, so I have used belongs_to in order model it giving error while creating order

> undefined method `orders' for #

1. when I use has_many :orders in customer model it works fine, why it
   does not work with only belongs_to
2. Its work with has_many :orders in customer model but not with
   has_one : order in customer controller it giving same above error.

thanks in advance.

Model :- order.rb

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  attr_accessible :order_date, :customer_id
end
```

Model :- customer.rb

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
end
```

controller :- orders.rb

```
  def create
     @customer = Customer.find_by_name(params[:name])
    @order = @customer.orders.new(:order_date => params[:orderdate] )

    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.save
        format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @order, status: :created, location: @order }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Technically, `belongs_to` *will* work without a matching `has_many` or `has_one`. If, for instance, you say that Order `belongs_to :customer`, you can call `.customer` on an Order object, and get a Customer object. 
What you can't do is call `.orders` on a Customer without telling it that it `has_many :orders` (or `.order`, in the case of `has_one`), because that method is created by the `has_many` declaration.

That said, I can't think of any reason you would ever want to only specify half of a relation. It's a terrible design choice, and you should not do it.

Edit: `has_one` doesn't create the `.collection` methods that `has_many` does. Per [the guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-one-association-reference):

> 4.2.1 Methods Added by has_one
>
> When you declare a has_one association, the declaring class
>   automatically gains four methods related to the association:
>
> ```
> association(force_reload = false) 
> association=(associate)
> build_association(attributes = {}) 
> create_association(attributes = {})
> ```

You'll note that there's no `.new` on that list. If you want to add an associated object, you can use `customer.build_order()`, or `customer.order = Order.new()`.

Comment: okay thanks. Its work fine for Belongs_to has_many, but in case of belongs_to has_one it gives error :- undefined method `new'.. @order = @customer.order.new(:order_date => params[:orderdate] ); @order.save;